# call template partial using a channel field?

Tags: embeds, template-partials

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible. I am definitely not succeeding.

What I need is to have a channel field that calls a template partial, preferably a text field where I can type in the name of the partial or a drop down menu, where the partial name can be selected.

The plan being that if in the entry form, the partial_name field was channel_x_partial, the channel_x_partial content would appear when the page is viewed in the browser.

The code below has not worked.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" limit="1" dynamic="no" entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}" disable="member_data|pagination"}
    {partial_name}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Am I way off base?  Would another type of embed work better?  The catch is I need this to be dynamic as different entries would call different partials.

Thank you in advance even if it is to let me know I am way way off base!

Peter T

Answer (score 0):

Providing your field short name is `partial_name`, have you tried this syntax?

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="channel_name"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
    entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"
    disable="member_data|pagination"}

    {{partial_name}}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Another option is to just use conditionals based on the field value if that doesn't work:

```
{exp:channel:entries ... }

     {if partial_name == "partial_1"}
         {my_partial_1}
     {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Other options are possible but we would need some more info, perhaps some expanded sample template code on what you want to accomplish.